# How to concatenate two json objects with Swifty JSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm using Swifty JSON (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). I have searched and found a close one here ([How to combine two SwiftyJSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427516/how-to-combine-two-swiftyjson-objects/30429447)). I have exactly the same question. But the answers don't work in my case. I need to **concatenate**, NOT to **merge** two objects.

```
        let jsonArray1 = JSON(["name": "Tome", "Age": 20])
        let jsonArray2 = JSON(["name": "Jack", "Age": 30])
```

what I want is a JSON object

```
{
 {"name": "Tom", "Age": 20},{"name": "Jack", "Age": 30}
}
```

I tried to use

```
let combined = JSON(jsonArray1.arrayObject! + jsonArray2.arrayObject!)
```

it didn't work, saying `.arrayObject` is `nil`. I also tried `.array`  it didn't work either. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The JSON objects are dictionaries and the desired output (a root dictionary without keys) is not possible

Comment: Btw forget about SwiftyJSON. You should be structuring your data and using Codable since Swift 4

Comment: @vadian Thanks for your inputs. Can't the desired output above be stored in a json file? I imagine this (a json file consisting multiple objects) is very common, right?

Comment: It can be an array of dictionaries, `[{"name": "Tom", "Age": 20},{"name": "Jack", "Age": 30}]`

Comment: @LeoDabus They API I'm using uses SwiftyJSON. btw, I'm a beginner. I see a lot of tutorials made in 2019 are still teaching SwiftyJSON. Plus, in Codable, you have to build a struct with all properties matching the JSON data structure, right? But in SwiftyJSON, you don't have to build any struct.

Comment: @vadian Thanks! I guess an array of dictionaries is what I was looking for. Do you know how I can create a ```JSON``` instance that looks like ```[{"name": "Tom", "Age": 20},{"name": "Jack", "Age": 30}]```

Comment: Again throw SwiftyJSON away. It will make your live much easier `struct Person: Codable { let name: String let age: Int }`

Comment: `let people: [Person] = [.init(name: "Tom", age: 20), .init(name: "Jack", age: 30)]`

`let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(people)`
`String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!`  // "[{"name":"Tom","age":20},{"name":"Jack","age":30}]"

Comment: @LeoDabus  I just read your messages because the comments were folded and I didn't notice that.  Thanks for your suggestion. The HTTP response I'm using is a json file with over 100 entries. I don't want to make a ```Struct:Codable ``` with 100 properties. With Swifty JSON, I can just do ```jsonArrary1["name"]``` without creating such a struct.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a slack channel, here is a solution

```
        let jsonArray1 = JSON(["name": "Tom", "Age": 20])
        let jsonArray2 = JSON(["name": "Jack", "Age": 30])
        var j = [JSON]()
        j.append(jsonArray1)
        j.append(jsonArray2)
        var jbody = JSON(j)
```

It seems that Swifty JSON struct takes an array of JSON instances in the initilizer. `jbody` has two json objects in it, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Why not much simpler `let jbody = JSON([jsonArray1, jsonArray2])`? And `jsonArray` is still `jsonDictionary` and you should take Leo's advice to drop `SwifyJSON`.

Comment: @vadianThanks! your code is more concise. Btw, I'm confused. ```jsonArray``` is a JSON struct. Why do you say ```jsonArray``` is a ```jsonDictionary```. btw2, the API I'm using uses Swifty JSON. I read that Codable has performance advantage. But Swifty JSON seems to be very easy to use, without creating structs, especially when json files have more than 100 entries.

Comment: `["name": "Tom", "Age": 20]` is not an array, it's a dictionary, so the variable name `jsonArray` is misleading and confusing. Codable is more efficient and easier to use, you get rid of all those `object["key"].stringValue` expressions because Codable is type safe.